# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and UserDetailsService creating circular dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, circular-dependency, userdetailsservice

My two following classes are creating a circular dependency

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private ApplicationUserServiceImpl applicationUserServiceImpl;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {
        this.applicationUserServiceImpl = applicationUserServiceImpl;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
    }


    @Service
    public class ApplicationUserServiceImpl implements ApplicationUserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public ApplicationUserServiceImpl(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationUser createUser(UserCreateDTO userCreateDTO) {
        if (applicationUserRepository.findByNickname(userCreateDTO.getNickname()).isPresent())
            throw new UserWithThatNicknameExistsException(
                    String.format(
                            "There is an existing user the nickname %s",
                            userCreateDTO.getNickname()));
        if (applicationUserRepository.findByEmail(userCreateDTO.getEmail()).isPresent())
            throw new UserWithThatEmailExistsException(
                    String.format(
                            "There is an existing user with the email %s",
                            userCreateDTO.getNickname()));
        ApplicationUser user =
                ApplicationUser.builder()
                        .nickname(userCreateDTO.getNickname())
                        .email(userCreateDTO.getEmail())
                        .biography(userCreateDTO.getBiography())
                        .password(passwordEncoder.encode(userCreateDTO.getPassword()))
                        .build();
        return applicationUserRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String nickname) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<ApplicationUser> applicationUser =
                applicationUserRepository.findByNickname(nickname);
        if (!applicationUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(nickname);
        }
        return new User(
                applicationUser.get().getNickname(),
                applicationUser.get().getPassword(),
                emptyList());
    }
}
```

I believe the passwordEncoder is responsible for the trouble but i am new with springboot so i am not sure.

this is the error body:

```
Description:
```

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  webSecurityConfig defined in file [/Users/nacholopez/IdeaProjects/ProjectA2Back/build/classes/java/main/com/a2/backend/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  applicationUserServiceImpl (field private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder com.a2.backend.service.impl.ApplicationUserServiceImpl.passwordEncoder)
└─────┘

2021-09-02 21:12:48.225 ERROR 86761 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@395b56bb] to prepare test instance [com.a2.backend.controller.ProjectControllerTest@62f68dff]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123) ~[spring-boot-test-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
... 102 common frames omitted

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

```
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/Users/nacholopez/IdeaProjects/ProjectA2Back/build/classes/java/main/com/a2/backend/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
... 68 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationUserServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
... 102 more

Process finished with exit code 255